# Ionic Angular App on startup stuck on splash screen with message ReferenceError: Can't find variable: _angular_router__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_51__

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am developing an IOS app using ionic v7 and angular v15.2. My app runs fine in the browser, but when I deploy my app to my Iphone (iphone 13 pro, running IOS 15.6) I get the following error message in XCode: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: *angular_router__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_51*_

[image: error message in XCode]

I am running `ionic cap run ios -l --external` to run my app on my phone. This command used to properly load my ionic app before I updated my ionic version from 4 to 7 and my angular from 12 to 15.

I have tried a number of things to fix this issue. I have looked through stackoverflow and other platforms trying to find someone else who has seen this error. I have tried reinstalling all of my npm packages and reinstalling my pods. I have also deleted and recloned my code, but nothing works.

I reviewed my platform start code:

```
async initializeApp() 
  {
    console.log('waiting starts!')

    SplashScreen.show({
      showDuration: 1000,
      autoHide: true
    });


    this.platform.ready().then(async() => 
    {
      console.log('waiting ends')
      if (this.platform.is('hybrid') && environment.simulator == false) {
        console.log('here!')
      }
      await SplashScreen.hide()
      if (Capacitor.isPluginAvailable('StatusBar')) {
        await StatusBar.hide();
      }
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }
```

This function runs in `app.component.ts` and I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Update: It looks like removing `{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }` from `app.module.ts` fixed the issue. To be honest, I'm not entirely sure why the app is now working fine, but since removing this line I haven't had any issues.